# Magento Layered Navigation - Hide Sub-sub categories

Tags: php, magento, layered-navigation

I'm currently developing a website for a client and I've hit a bit of a snag.

We're using FME Layered Navigation, which currently displays both sub & sub-sub categories of the parent category.

What we'd like is to just show the sub categories, then once that is clicked show the sub-sub categories.

e.g:

```
Root
  Cat1
    SubCat1
      SubSubCat1   /* Hide until SubCat1 is clicked */
      SubSubCat2   /* Hide until SubCat1 is clicked */
      SubSubCat3   /* Hide until SubCat1 is clicked */
    SubCat2  
      SubSubCat1   /* Hide until SubCat2 is clicked */
      SubSubCat2   /* Hide until SubCat2 is clicked */
      SubSubCat3   /* Hide until SubCat2 is clicked */
    SubCat3
      SubSubCat1   /* Hide until SubCat3 is clicked */
      SubsubCat2   /* Hide until SubCat3 is clicked */
      SubSubCat3   /* Hide until SubCat3 is clicked */
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction please? I've looked through the /app/code/local/FME .phtml files, but I can't see anything that decides the level of category to display.

Answer (score 1):

update your catalog.xml in your app/design/default/THEMENAME/layout/catalog.xml with this XML definition to remove the category filters from the left-layered navigation in Magento.

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to

```
System >> Configurations >> Developer
```

then select the respective store view from `Current Configuration Scope` from top left drop-down. Then under `Debug` tab, enable the `Template Paht hints` and `Add Block Names to Hints`  and save. Now reload your frontend where the navigation is displayed. you will find the proper `.phtml` and the `block` name that were used.